# I want to optimize this program

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

I have recently started to learn c and as a programming exercise, I've written a program that computes and lists out prime numbers from 0 up to a maximum entered by the user. It's a rather short program so I'll post the source code here.

```
// playground.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int max;
    printf("Please enter the maximum number up to which you would like to see all primes listed: "
      );   scanf("%i", &max);

    printf("All prime numbers in the range 0 to %i:\nPrime number: 2\n", max);


    bool isComposite;
    int primesSoFar[(max >> 1) + 1];
    primesSoFar[0] = 2;
    int nextIdx = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
        isComposite = false;
        for (int k = 2; k <= (int)sqrt(i) + 1; k++)
        {
            if (k - 2 < nextIdx)
            {
                if (i % primesSoFar[k - 2] == 0)
                {
                    isComposite = true;
                    k = primesSoFar[k - 2];
                }
            }else
            {
                if (i % k == 0) isComposite = true;
            }

        }
        if (!isComposite)
        {
            printf("Prime number: %i\n", i);
            primesSoFar[nextIdx] = i;
            nextIdx++;

        }

    }

    double primeRatio = (double)(nextIdx + 1) / (double)(max);
    printf("The ratio of prime numbers to composites in range 0 to %d is %lf", max, primeRatio);

    return 0;
}
```

I have become strangely fascinated with optimizing this program but I've hit a wall. The array `primesSoFar` is allocated based on a computed maximum size which ideally would be no larger than the number of prime numbers from 0 to `max`. Even if it were just slightly larger, that would be fine; as long as it's not smaller. Is there a way to compute the size the array needs to be that doesn't depend on first computing the primes up to `max`?

I've updated the code both applying suggested optimizations and adding internal documentation wherever it seemed helpful.

```
// can compute all the primes up to 0x3FE977 (4_188_535). Largest prime 4_188_533

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int max;
    printf("Please enter the maximum number up to which you would like to see all primes listed: "
      );   scanf("%i", &max);

    // The algorithm proper doesn't print 2.
    printf("All prime numbers in the range 0 to %i:\nPrime number: 2\n", max);


    bool isComposite;
    // primesSoFar is a memory hog. It'd be nice to reduce its size in proportion to max. The frequency
    // of primes diminishes at higher numerical ranges. A formula for calculating the number of primes for
    // a given numerical range would be nice. Sadly, it's not linear.
    int PRIMES_MAX_SIZE = (max >> 1) + 1;
    int primesSoFar[PRIMES_MAX_SIZE];
    primesSoFar[0] = 2;
    int nextIdx = 1;
    int startConsecCount = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
        isComposite = false; // Assume the current number isn't composite.
        for (int k = 2; k <= (int)sqrt(i) + 1; k++)
        {
            if (k - 2 < nextIdx) // Check it against all primes found so far.
            {
                if (i % primesSoFar[k - 2] == 0)
                {
                    // If i is divisible by a previous prime number, break.
                    isComposite = true;
                    break;
                }else
                {
                    // Prepare to start counting consecutive integers at the largest prime + 1. if i 
                    // isn't divisible by any of the primes found so far.
                    startConsecCount = primesSoFar[k - 2] + 1;
                }
            }else
            {
                if (startConsecCount != 0) // Begin counting consecutively at the largest prime + 1.
                {
                    k = startConsecCount;
                    startConsecCount = 0;
                }

                if (i % k == 0)
                {
                    // If i is divisible by some value of k, break.
                    isComposite = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if (!isComposite)
        {
            printf("Prime number: %i\n", i);

            if (nextIdx < PRIMES_MAX_SIZE)
            {
                // If the memory allocated for the array is sufficient to store an additional prime, do so.
                primesSoFar[nextIdx] = i;
                nextIdx++;
            }

        }

    }

    // I'm using this to get data with which I can find a way to compute a smaller size for primesSoFar.
    double primeRatio = (double)(nextIdx + 1) / (double)(max);
    printf("The ratio of prime numbers to composites in range 0 to %d is %lf\n", max, primeRatio);

    return 0;
}
```

**edit:** `primesSoFar` should be half the size of the range 0 to max. No doubt that's caused some confusion.

Comment: You can read about that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: You should learn about Sieve: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/)

Comment: Don't miss the Sieve of Atkin either

Comment: Here's a state of the art sieve implementation: https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some debugging to be done first.

When I saw that the test was **<=** my brain said BUG as Arrays are subscripted from 0 .. max - 1.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
```

So I went to look at the array.

```
int primesSoFar[(max >> 1) + 1];
```

Oh he is adding one to the size so it should be ok.
Wait.  Why is that shift in there?  **(max >> 1)** is a divide by two.

I compiled the code and ran it, and MSVC reported a memory error.
I removed the shift, and the memory error report went away.  The program worked as expected.

With that out of the way, *PiNaKa30* and *II Saggio Vecchino* have very good advice.  The choice of algorithm is going to effect the performance dramatically.

*Mat* gives very good advice.  Read the Wikipedia entry.  It is filled with wonderful information.

- Picking the correct algorithm is key.
- How you represent the data you are checking is a factor.  **int** has a maximum value it can hold.
- A performance [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) can tell you lots of useful information about where the [Hot Spots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_spot_(computer_programming)) are in your program.

Congratulations on your efforts in learning C.  You picked a very good learning path.

Comment: The shift is in there because no integer factor of the largest number being evaluated will be more than half the maximum. The list isn't for storing all of the primes, it's for storing those primes which are useful to searching for factors to the current number being factored, `i`, which will never exceed max. For safety, I can add a check to see whether there is still space in the array before adding new elements but the goal is actually to make `primesSoFar` _less_ of a memory hog.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll implement changes to my program.

Comment: I suggest putting the array size in a variable, and using that to add your check.

Comment: What platform are you running on?  A profiler will change the way you look at the program.

Comment: A possible optimization is to break out of the K loop when you find that the I you are testing is composite.

Comment: I am running Linux Mint and using GCC with the c standard libraries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203849/discussion-between-evilteach-and-kyle-eames).

Answer (score 3):

I can give you two main ideas as I have worked on a project discussing this problem.

1. A prime number bigger than 3 is either `6k-1` or `6k+1`, so for example 183 can't be prime because `183=6x30+3`, so you don't even have to check it. (Be careful, this condition is necessary but not sufficient, `25` for exemple is `6x4+1` but is not prime)
2. A number is prime if it can't be divided by any prime number smaller or equal to its root, so it's preferable to take a benefit out of the smaller primes you already found.

Thus, you can start with a `primesList` containing `2` and `3`, and iterate `k` to test all the `6k-1` and `6k+1` numbers (`5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25...`) using the second rule I gave you, by using division on elements in the `primesList` which are smaller than or equal to the root of the number you are checking, if you found only one element dividing it, you just stop and pass to another element, 'cause this one is not prime, otherwise (if no one can divide it): update the `primesList` by adding this new prime number.

Comment: As it is a necessary condition not a sufficient condition, I'm not sure how to use the check `i == 6 * k - 1 || i == 6 * k + 1` to make my algorithm run faster. I appreciate your insight, but I would need a way of skipping checks of integers where `!(i == 6 * k - 1 || i == 6 * k + 1)` without adding any overhead.

Comment: `for(k=1; 6*k-1&lt;max; k++){int k1=6*k-1, k2=6*k+1; /* Do the work */}` or you can use the moduli operator.

Comment: I may add comments to the code I've posted to help clarify it. Concerning point 2, the inner for loop does perform a check of primes added to primesSoFar before it moves on to consecutive integer values larger than the largest prime that's been added. I'm unsure what's being suggested though I did add break statements in both cases where a number is found to be composite and it sped up my program considerably. Frankly, I'm rather embarrassed of that oversight.

Answer (score 0):

The source code that follows is basically a rewrite. It's running now as I write this. I entered `0x7FFF_FFFF`, the 32-bit signed integer positive maximum. In mere minutes on my Acer aspire laptop running on an AMD ryzen 3 with Linux Mint it's already in the hundreds of millions! The memory usage of the old version was half of max, rendering anything larger than `0x3EF977` impossible on my 4gb of RAM. Now it only uses 370728 bytes of memory for its array data when computing primes from 0 to 2_147_483_647.

```
/*
  A super optimized prime number generator using my own implementation of the sieve of Eratosthenes.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int max;
    printf("Please enter the maximum to which you would like to see all primes listed: "
      ); scanf("%i", &max);

    /*
      Primes and their multiples will be stored until the next multiple of the prime is larger than max.
      That prime and its corresponding multiple will then be replaced with a new prime and its corresponding
      multiple.
    */
    int PRIMES_MAX_SIZE = (int)sqrt(max) + 1;
    int primes[PRIMES_MAX_SIZE];
    int multiples[PRIMES_MAX_SIZE];
    primes[0] = 2;
    multiples[0] = 2;
    int nextIdx = 1;

    int const NO_DISPOSE_SENTINAL_VALUE = -1;
    int nextDispose = NO_DISPOSE_SENTINAL_VALUE;
    int startConsecCount = 0;
    int updateFactor;
    bool isComposite;

    printf("All prime numbers in the range 0 to %i:\n\n", max);
    // Iterate from i = 2 to i = max and test each i for primality.
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
        isComposite = false;
        /*
          Check whether the current i is prime by comparing it with the current multiples of
          prime numbers, updating them when they are less than the current i and then proceeding
          to check whether any consecutive integers up to sqrt(i) divide the current i evenly.
        */
        for (int k = 2; k < (int)sqrt(i) + 1; k++)
        {
            if (k < nextIdx)
            {
                // Update the multiple of a prime if it's smaller than the current i.
                if (multiples[k] < i)
                {
                    updateFactor = (int)(i / primes[k]);
                    multiples[k] = updateFactor * primes[k] + primes[k];
                    // Mark the value for disposal if it's greater than sqrt(max).
                    if (multiples[k] > (int)sqrt(max)) nextDispose = k;
                }
                if (i == multiples[k])
                {
                    isComposite = true;
                    break;
                }else
                {
                    startConsecCount = multiples[k] + 1;
                }
            } else
            {
                if (startConsecCount != 0)
                {
                    k = startConsecCount;
                    startConsecCount = 0;
                }
                if (i % k == 0)
                {
                    isComposite = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        /*
          Print the prime numbers and either insert them at indices occupied by disposed primes or at
          the next array index if available.
        */
        if (!isComposite)
        {
            printf("Prime number: %i\n", i);

            if (nextDispose != NO_DISPOSE_SENTINAL_VALUE)
            {
                primes[nextDispose] = i;
                // This will trigger the update code before the comparison in the inner loop.
                multiples[nextDispose] = 0;
                nextDispose = NO_DISPOSE_SENTINAL_VALUE;
            }else
            {
                if (nextIdx < PRIMES_MAX_SIZE)
                {
                    primes[nextIdx] = i;
                    multiples[nextIdx] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This thing will do the old 0 to 0x3EF977 in the blink of an eye. The old version couldn't do the 32-bit maximum on my system. It's on 201 million + already. I am super chuffed with the results. Thank you for your advice. I wouldn't have made it this far without help.

Comment: Consider an optimization using bit arrays.  http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html

Comment: That's a very clever idea. I was thinking of using some kind of lossless compression scheme. The challenge in either case would be getting the least processing overhead for the memory savings gained. primes2.c, the implementation above your comment actually keeps track of what prime number data it no longer needs and overwrites it in a kind of crude garbage collection. Even this simple improvement to memory usage has slowed down the program by about 30%.

Comment: So, it turns out that the idea to try to garbage collect primes that have no further use was rubbish! I was just fortunate enough that the logic was set up in such a way that it didn't prevent my program from working. It did slow it down though as execution would proceed straight to testing consecutive integer values after checking 2! I've fixed the code and will post it on GitHub. If this comment gets enough up votes, I'll share a link. I just don't want to spam this forum.

Comment: Here's a link to the final version of my primes program. [My GitHub](https://github.com/keames1/hello-world) I'll be continuing to write the compiler for my language now.